# Here to place header files in CLION

Tags: c++, header-files

guys am using clion 2017 because my laptop is only 2gb ram am still a beginner and I don't know where to place header files in order to work I downloaded the files like std_lib_facilities.h but i don't know the directory I need to place it in so I usually replace it by

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open(){char ch; cin>>ch;}
```

but I am looking forward to start using header files correctly so where to place it?

Comment: Anywhere you want, then specify the path in your project settings (probably in `CMakeLists.txt`). Preferably **not** into the compiler installation directory.

Comment: Your choice, preferrably in a position that allows easy navigation from implementation to source files in the file system. For public headers of a library you probably want to create a separate directory containing only public headers and possibly also place the dir in another dir that's otherwise empty to allow you to inlcude the file using `#include <mylib/myheader.hpp>`; you could achieve this by placing the header at `include/mylib/myheader.hpp` relative to the dir containing `CMakeLists.txt` allowing you to do `target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)`...